# Data and Breakpoint window not showing in SQL dev

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

While debugging in SQL developer SMART DATA and DATA window are not showing.enter image description here

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those only appear during a debug session.

If you don't see them during your debug session, try opening them manually.

[image]

If it's still not appearing, try resetting your desktop layout.

Window - Reset Windows to Factory Settings

Comment: Excuse me sir but do you happen to know where I can find the stack window for debugging? (20.2)

Comment: Try Windows, reset to factory settings